# Kafka two authentication methods and different list of topics why?

Tags: apache-kafka

Dears,

I have strange problem which I don't understand. In our kafka configuration we are using two methods of authentication:

```
listeners=INSIDE://:9091,OUTSIDE1://:9093,OUTSIDE2://:9092
advertised.listeners=INSIDE://kafka1:9091,OUTSIDE1://kafka1:9093,OUTSIDE2://kafka1:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INSIDE:SASL_SSL,OUTSIDE1:SASL_SSL,OUTSIDE2:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=INSIDE
```

when I trying to list of all topics for both methods of authentication I've got differ amount of topics:

port 9092:

```
 /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server kafka1:9092 |wc -l
107
```

vs port 9093:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server kafka1:9093 --command-config /root/admin-ssl.properties|wc -l
141
```

I totally don't understand why the amount of topics is different. Any idea?

Best Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You probably have ACL's that are only applied to whatever authentication method on 9092.

You can see ACL's with the following command

> kafka-acls.sh --bootstrap-server kafka1:9093 --command-config /root/admin-ssl.properties --list --topic

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I checked the amount of acl's for both methods of authentication before I posted the question here and the amount of acl's is the same and problematic topics are on both lists of acl's but when I show list of topic's for both methods of authentication only one list (SASL_SSL:9093) include the problematic topic and second list (PLAINTEXT:9092) not include.

Comment: My acl's were created in this way:
```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=kafka1:2181 --add --allow-principal User:app --operation All --topic new_topic
```
and such topic is visible on the list of topics from port SASL_SSL:9093 only not in case of PLAINTEXT:9092.
What does it means for me? Should I create proper acl's for both authorization methods separately during creation of any new topic?

Comment: Are there any errors in your broker logs? I found strange issues like this after I changed some config and brokers were erroring out talking to zookeeper.

Comment: There are no errors in the logs. When I added new acl's: "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --remove --allow-principal User:ANONYMOUS --operation Read --topic '*'" them list of topics from both ports are the same.